# Perl CGI script with css

Tags: css, perl, cgi

I am using a external css for my CGI web form but I can't get the .css to take to the page. Is there a certain way a external css needs to be called. I tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/archiveRequest.css" media="screen" />
```

which has not been working. I have tried moving the css in the same folder as the .cgi with still no results.

Comment: All looks well with that declaration, I imagine you just have it pointing at a wrong directory.

Comment: As mentioned below, if styles is at the top level, just lose the ".."

Comment: The directory is not the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `href` attribute needs to be in relation to the page you're viewing in your browser. For example, if your URL is `http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/mypage.cgi` then, with your above code, your CSS file needs to be viewable in a browser at `http://www.example.com/styles/archiveRequest.css`. Try loading it up directly in your browser using the direct URL. Also take a look at your server logs, and you'll probably find 404 errors showing where the file is trying to be loaded from.

Comment: I was able to load the /styles/archiveRequest.css page in my browser.

Comment: @James: Then there's some other problem. Look at your requests in Firebug or Chrome's developer mode. Look at your server logs. Those will shed light on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you were "able to load the /styles/archiveRequest.css", then use  "/styles/archiveRequest.css" as href too.

Comment: That is exactly what my problem is. I do use that as my href and it still does not work.

Comment: @james: and if you use it as URL?

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked quite a while ago, but I had the same problem today and spent hours looking for an answer.  This is what worked for me:

If my cgi script is */var/cgi-bin/test.cgi*, putting my style.css file in the same directory did not work.  Apparently this makes it get treated like a script, which it isn't.  I moved my style file to */var/www/styles/style.css* and made it non-executable (but readable).

In a browser, I was able to see it at *localhost/styles/style.css*, so in my cgi script I referenced it as:

my $stylesheet = "/styles/style.css";
start_html(-style=>{'src'=>$stylesheet}), 
....

Hope this is useful to someone else.

(The answer that helped me was found here: http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=113842)